# Marketing Cloud User and Role data pull

Tags: userrecordaccess, sql

Trying to pull user and role data to cover t eh following.  Is there any Reports or SQL out there that can help with this?

1. List of all users
2. Business Unit and what roles are assigned to each user
3. Usage statistics if possible
4. Description of capabilities used if possible